# Is there a way to get a developer account to avoid being confused with an automated tool?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm currently developing a Chrome extension to use with LinkedIn Sales, and I'm having issues while testing the front end.

Due to some style changes, I had to refresh the page multiple times and now my account is temporarily banned because they confused me with an automated tool.

Does anyone know a workaround for this? Or, alternatively, can I create some type of developer account to use?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

> Due to some style changes, I had to refresh the page multiple times

This is really a suspicious action.

So isn't your "Chrome extension" also an automated tool?
Either get some API access (you find available APIs here https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog)

or if you just do some visual brush-up for users, you could try to make an offline copy of the page once (with a tool like [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/)) and then use that copy for development.

For the Sales API it says

> It's required that all integrations are built by approved partners for the SNAP program. To become a partner, visit [this page](https://business.linkedin.com/sales-solutions/partners/become-a-partner).

Comment: Hi cyberbrain, no, it's not an automated tool. I was trying some CSS, that's the reason behind the refreshing.
Thanks for the offline copy idea, didn't know it was possible! :)